# React-Bootstrap dropdown button width increasing with title prop value length

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, scss-lint

I am using React Bootstrap dropdown. Here is the code

```
<DropdownButton
            title={userFormattedAdress === undefined ? title : (userFormattedAdress)}
            variant="outline"
            drop={"down"}
          >

            <Dropdown.Item onClick={getUserCurrentLocation} >
              Use Current Location
            </Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Divider />

            <Dropdown.Item onClick={openMapModal} >
              Change Current Location
            </Dropdown.Item>

</DropdownButton>
```

What I am doing is basically on selecting of current location and change location saving that address information in the title of DropdownButton but the issue is the size or width of the dropdown keeps on increasing with the length of the address I am receiving.

How to resolve it. Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed/max width to `.dropdown-item` but, obviously, it will cut off the text. You can add y-scroll to the parent but that will look ugly. So either you use wide dropdown (style the dropdown button as an input instead of a button - with some default value) or truncate the text with '...' and , may be, add some popup on hover with full text.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 approaches that I can think of -

1. Wrap the text to another line using css.
2. Use "text-overflow: ellipsis" in css to add "..." if the text overflows the max width.
3. If you do not want to go the css route, you can carry out a string manipulation in js to set the string to the maximum desired character count.

Choose the option that fits your use case.

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069374/react-bootstrap-dropdown-button-width-increasing-with-title-prop-value-length

Can you check my question here for better understanding of the problem